# Ensamblado de proyectos mavenizados

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

Tengo un proyecto principal (compuesto por varios proyectos/módulos maven) y un proyecto auxiliar. Todos los proyectos están mavenizados, el principal es padre de sus módulos y el proyecto auxiliar no tiene padre.

El objetivo es crear un único jar, que contenga las clases de los proyectos que forman el principal y las clases de mi proyecto módulo.

EDIT 1: He creado un proyecto Maven aparte, que incluya todos los proyectos y módulos anteriormente citados y he conseguido crear un jar con todas las clases (compiladas) de todos los proyectos, pero ahora me quedan dos puntos por tratar:

- El proyecto auxiliar tiene ficheros xml que no aparecen dentro del jar, creo que he de tocar el includes pero no me funciona
- Soy incapaz de crear un jar con los sources java sin compilar

¿En qué estoy fallando?

Así tengo el pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.grupo</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProyectoPadre</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.otro</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProyectoAuxiliar</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Y el descriptor bin es el siguiente:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
<id>bin</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>com.test.grupo:Modulo1</include>
            <include>com.test.grupo:Modulo2</include>
            <include>com.test.otro:ProyectoAuxiliar</include>
        </includes>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </unpackOptions>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <useProjectAttachments>false</useProjectAttachments>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace un tiempo que saque la respuesta, pero se me olvido indicarla por si en un futuro, alguien la necesitase.

Este sería mi pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classProject</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly-sources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly/sources.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.grupo</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProyectoPadre</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(Tuve un problema con el directorio por defecto donde se guardaban las clases, es por eso que lo guardo en classProject)

Y el descriptor quedaría así:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
<id>sources</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>com.test.grupo:Modulo1:jar:sources</include>
            <include>com.test.grupo:Modulo2:jar:sources</include>
        </includes>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <useProjectAttachments>false</useProjectAttachments>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>assembly/*.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```